# Is there way to recover unstaged files

Tags: git, gitlab, data-recovery, sublimemerge

I staged some files, after did many edits then by mistake hit <kbd>commit</kbd> button in sublime merge so many of my files did not committed and only some of them were committed, I wanted to revert it but then I did abort revert so my all files lost. Is there any way to recover that?

Comment: "Unstaged" files are in your working tree, *not* in Git at all. You can recover them using system recovery tools, or editor recovery files, or whatever, if those are available—but because they're not *in* Git in the first place, they cannot be recovered *by* Git. Once you *commit* files, Git makes a new permanent snapshot: Git can recover any *commit*. You say you hit the "commit" button, so that presumably committed them, but that's a question about your IDE, not about Git.

Comment: In addition, if your situation was that you commited before you were ready but without all of the files, you can `stage` additional files and then `amend` the previously made commit so that it includes all the changes. Also, for what it's worth I don't think your question is specific to Sublime Merge except tht that was the front end you were using at the time

Comment: Do you still see the commit in your commit history? If so, create a new branch from there. Its unclear to me whether you lost -all- your files or just the staged files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use : **git checkout 5687e59 --filename.txt**

It retrieves the old version of the file which is before the commit made to the staging area and working directory.
Use **git diff -- staged** to view the retrieved file with changes.

> Here 5687e59 is the Commit id.